# ASP.NET vNext EF7 dbContext issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am starting a vNext project, and I'm having some issues kicking it off the ground. I have added a table to the `ApplicationDbContext` class, and it successfully created the table in the db (which in my case is in Azure). However, I can't seem to correctly instantiate a `dbContext` to use in my Controllers.

In my experience with previous ASP.NET EF projects, I could instantiate the ApplicationDbContext class without passing it any parameters, but in the case of vNext however, it seems to expect a number of things (`IServiceProvider`, and `IOptionsAccessor<DbContextOptions>`). I have tried creating a parameter-less constructor, but the App breaks due to not knowing what connection strings to use. My code is below -- as you see in the `OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)` override, I force the connection string in via the `DbContextOptions`, but that's obviously not ideal, and I feel like I'm just not understanding where those two `IServiceProvider`, and IOptionsAccessor parameters need to come from.

Thanks for any help!

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        private static bool _created = false;

        public DbSet<Business> Businesses { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base()
        {
            if (!_created)
            {
                Database.EnsureCreated();
                _created = true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
        {
            var configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.AddJsonFile("config.json");
            configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"));
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IOptionsAccessor<DbContextOptions> optionsAccessor)
            : base(serviceProvider, optionsAccessor.Options)
        {            
            // Create the database and schema if it doesn't exist
            // This is a temporary workaround to create database until Entity Framework database migrations 
            // are supported in ASP.NET vNext
            if (!_created)
            {
                Database.EnsureCreated();
                _created = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Using EF7 in Traditional .NET Applications](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Using-EF7-in-Traditional-.NET-Applications) may help you a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IServiveProvider and IOptionAccessor are injected by the Dependency Injection 
the ASP.Net Core DI has limitation, you cannot have more than one constructor.

Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx